# How do I nunmap `=` mapping created by vimwiki?

Tags: vim

I recently started using `vimwiki` and observed that the `=` command is broken because it does not handle counts correctly.

I wanted to remap it in a way that handles counts correctly, but I cannot seem to unmap it.

Here's the output of `:map =`.

```
n  =            @<Plug>VimwikiAddHeaderLevel
```

Here's the output of `:nunmap =`.

```
E31: No such mapping
```

How do I unmap this mapping manually from a session?

Comment: If you plan to override the mapping, anyway, there's no need to `:unmap` it first.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, Fair point. I posted this question and then answer because I thought it might be broadly useful for people. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the plugin's source, I discovered that it was using a buffer-local mapping. It seems that such mappings can only be removed with a buffer-local `unmap` command.

```
:nunmap <buffer> =
```

Answer (score 0):

`:help vimwiki_key_mappings`

The easiest way to unmap a group of vimwiki mappings is:

```
  let g:vimwiki_key_mappings =
    \ {
    \ 'headers': 0,
    \ 'text_objs': 0,
    \ }
```

To unmap all mappings, use:

```
let g:vimwiki_key_mappings = { 'all_maps': 0, }
```

To remove one specific keymap, one dirty hack you can do is to remove the place it's mapped in your local plugin's source. In case of vimwiki installed with Vundle, it's in `~/.vim/bundle/vimwiki/ftplugin/vimwiki.vim`.
To remove the = mapping, delete [this line](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/63af6e72dd3fa840bffb3ebcb8c96970c02e0913/ftplugin/vimwiki.vim#L655). (Obviously your changes would be wiped out on the next plugin update).